# Parameterized hibernate query causing where clause failure

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

The following code snippet works as expected, returning a list containing a dozen rows.

```
String hql = "select assetDate, sum(variable) as variable from Table where assetDate >= '30-JUN-19' and assetDate < '30-JUN-20' and ver= '"+ver+"' group by assetDate order by assetDate";

List results = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

This code, however, returns an empty list, but no errors.

```
String hql = "select assetDate, sum(variable) as variable from Table where assetDate >= '30-JUN-19' and assetDate < '30-JUN-20' and ver= :ver group by assetDate order by assetDate";

List results = session.createQuery(hql).setString("ver",ver).list();
```

I cannot understand what might be causing the difference here.

In the log, I can see:

```
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [the correct value]
```

So it looks like the variable is being bound properly, but since the output is incorrect, it clearly isn't. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening internally to cause this difference?
The column ver in the source table is of type CHAR( 20 BYTE), which is the only thing I can think of that might cause a problem, but even that seems somewhat unlikely.

Comment: Aren't you missing a quote after the first date? Or is that copy&paste error?

Comment: That is indeed a copy paste error. Fixed now.

Comment: I'd try using the Oracle profiler and see exactly how the query is coming in. That'll probably give you a hint. It looks ok on the surface.

Comment: Having a wild guess, could you give an `alias` to the table and then use `alias.ver = :ver`

Comment: The `CHAR(20)` column type is most probably the problem. Change it to `VARCHAR2`. To match a `CHAR(20)` column you must pass a string padded with blanks to exact 20 byte length.

Comment: Also you probably want to use an explicit date format. Change `assetDate < '30-JUN-20'` to `assetDate < date '2020-06-30'` - that syntax will work everywhere regardless of client settings.